# Correct way to handle navigation in offline Jquery Mobile app for iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery mobile app that became completely broken on iOS the moment I add offline support via an application cache manifest as described here:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6494

There is lots of discussion about this but I have yet to find a clear answer as to whether I can have offline support on mobile safari and preserve the nice looking transitions of Jquery Mobile.

Can it be done?

Comment: How about generating pages dynamically, appending to the DOM and then calling changepage. JQM will find the page and changepage without Ajax, so you should have no problems offline.

Comment: I actually made some progress using this prefilter code to set isLocal: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1579#issuecomment-1209338
But when I save it to the home page it won't launch offline. It is requesting the root of the site e.g if it is at foo.com that is what it is requesting.
I tried putting a fallback for / to index.html but it still fails in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. This was what I did:

- Apply prefilter as per [Using the Application Cache](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)
- change any href="#" to href="index.html"
- change any dialog("close") to $.mobile.changePage('index.html')

The only weirdness remains is that in order for it to work offline the app must be launched twice after being added to the home screen.